# How can I know the value of parameters?

Tags: plotting, functions, list-manipulation

In the the attached image I plot two function for the parameter $a1, a2, a4$. I take $a2$ as particular value, $a1$ as discrete set and $a4$ continuous value. In the plot how can i recognize for which value of $a1$ which plot is making? In shot I want to know the values of $a1$ for each curve and print it(may be by changing colour or using legend). Is it possible?

```
a1 = Range[-1, 10];
a2 = 100;
p2 = (3*a2 + 4*a4);
p1 = Sqrt[(p2)^2 + 8*a1*(a2 + a4)];
p3 = 1 + (2*a1*(a2 + 2*a4))/(p1 + p2);

t1 = p3;
t2 = (1 + a1/p3);
Plot[{t1, t2}, {a4, 0, 100}]
```

Output is---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If we start by making a list of your expressions then we can give a legend or a tooltip for each.

```
a1 = Range[-1, 10];
a2 = 100;
p2 = (3*a2 + 4*a4);
p1 = Sqrt[(p2)^2 + 8*a1*(a2 + a4)];
p3 = 1 + (2*a1*(a2 + 2*a4))/(p1 + p2);

t1 = p3;
t2 = (1 + a1/p3);
e = Join[t1, t2];
```

You have 24 equations so we need 24 colours.

```
Plot[e, {a4, 0, 100}, PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Range[24]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

An alternative would be to use a `Tooltip`

```
Plot[Tooltip[ e], {a4, 0, 100}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This does not look very exciting but when you hover over the line you will see the corresponding equation.

Going to 3D might help. First I extract the lines and colours from a 2d plot

```
pp = Plot[Tooltip[ e], {a4, 0, 100}];
lines = Cases[pp, Line[a_], Infinity];
col = Cases[pp, RGBColor[a__], Infinity];
```

Then we make a 3d plot

```
Graphics3D[
 Table[{col[[i]], lines[[i]] /. {x_, y_} :> {x, i, y}}, {i, 
   Length@lines}], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.5}, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which can be rotated to see all the curves.  To index these we could do

```
Graphics3D[
 Table[{col[[i]], 
   Text[ToString[i], {lines[[i]][[1, 1, 1]], i, 
     lines[[i]][[1, 1, 2]]}], 
   lines[[i]] /. {x_, y_} :> {x, i, y}}, {i, Length@lines}], 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.5}, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]